# Request TextField focus in initState

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a login page with a UID and PWD TextField.  UID, once provided is stored in shared preferences.  Therefore, whenever the login screen si shown, the focus could be either on the UID TextField (if no UID is provided/stored) or on the PWD TextField (if UID is shown or provided and automatically populated).

The problem I have is that I am trying to set the focus to the correct TextField using:

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_uidFocusNode)
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_pwdFocusNode);
```

Where the _uidFocusNode and _pwdFocusNode are defined as FocusNodes and attached to the appropriate TextFields via the focusNode property.

Now, I cannot set the focus using the above statements in initState since the Widget has not been built yet.  But when I set it in the build method, it causes a rebuild and the field with focus is blinking all the time.  Is there a way to set the focus when building a Widget depending on logic?  Note that autofocus does not work as expected - I need the cursor to be int he field.

Comment: Are you talking about an iOS/Android app or a web app, please? It's quite of a difference since autofocus is not working on web at the time of writing (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58498)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! You can schedule a function to be called after the build is done using [`SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html).
You can simply use it in your `initState`:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration _) {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(condition ? _pwdFocusNode : _uidFocusNode);
  });
}
```

Make sure to add `import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: @creativecreatormaybenot, this is perfect.  Following your advice I Google addPostFrameCallback and came to this amazing article which not only explained why but also corrected your answer a bit to use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback.  Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: @lgor I am glad you liked my answer. However, you misinterpreted the part about `WidgetsBinding` because it does not matter. `SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` are **exactly** the same because [`WidgetsBinding`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding-mixin.html) *inherits* the method from `SchedulerBinding`.

Comment: you're right but I could not call `SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback` since it's not a static function and i did not know how to get at the function `addPostFrameCallback()` inside `initState()`.

Comment: @Igor I am sorry. You need to access the instance using `SchedulerBinding.instance`. See the code snippet in the answer.